# Finding a path between two lists

Tags: list, prolog

I've been tasked with the portion of the code that reads through two lists and finds a path between the two lists.

My problem is however with reading and returning a TRUE case if I find the required node in the first list. I've been writing my code as below.

```
%declare the list
circle_line([cc1,cc2,cc3,cc4,cc5,cc6,cc7,cc8,cc9,cc10,cc11,cc12,cc13,cc14,cc15,cc16]).   

%the predicate that finds the station i need
check_for_station(A) :- circle_line(X),
            member(A,X),
            write(A),nl.
```

Then in the cosole I type: `check_for_station(cc9)`.

But the answer I get is "no."
I have a feeling that I'm declaring the list wrong, because in the debugger the value of X comes out to be "H135" or something and it clearly does not loop through every element to find the one that I need.

Comment: which implementation of prolog are you using? i tried in swi-prolog (5.10.1) and it works fine (2?- check_for_station(cc9).
cc9
true )

Comment: It also works for GNU prolog 1.3.0

Comment: hi, ive been trying with Amzi! Prolog 3.5.9..... ill try downloading and coding with swi-prolog(5.10.1).. thanks guys..

Comment: I'm not sure if that was the error, but what i did in Azmi! was to load more libraries and it WORKED ! ... thanks for helping me to check my code guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As whythehack found, in Amzi! Prolog the classic (and nondeterministic) **member/2** predicate is not a "built-in" but is provided (along with other useful list manipulation predicates like **length/2**) in the [list library](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/libs/list.htm).  See [here](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_text.htm#ListProcessing) for some context about the built-in versus library predicates for lists.

If **check_for_station/1** is only to be called with its argument `A` bound (as the example suggests), then Amzi!'s built-in (and deterministic) predicate **is_member/2** will do the job (and a bit more quickly).

The thinking seems to be that nondeterministic **member/2** is a two-line user-definition, and providing a faster deterministic version (not permitting backtracking over members of a list) is something the user could not easily provide for themselves.